# Load partial shapefile into Postgis / GeoDjango project

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, geodjango, django

I have a shapefile with Canadian postal codes, but am only looking to load a small subset of the data. I can load the entire data file and use SQL or Django queries to prune the data, but the load process takes about 2 hours on the slower machines I'm using.

As the data I'm actually after is about 10% of the dataset, this isn't a very efficient process.

I'm following the instructions in the [Geodjango tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/layermapping/), specifically the following code:

```
from django.contrib.gis.utils import LayerMapping
from geoapp.models import TestGeo
mapping = {'name' : 'str', # The 'name' model field maps to the 'str' layer field.
               'poly' : 'POLYGON', # For geometry fields use OGC name.
               } # The mapping is a dictionary
lm = LayerMapping(TestGeo, 'test_poly.shp', mapping)
lm.save(verbose=True) # Save the layermap, imports the data.
```

Is there a way to only only import data with a particular name, as in the example above?

I'm limited to the Linux / OS X command line, so wouldn't be able to utilize any GUI tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data to filter is not too complex, use the OGDL/GDAL filtering to reduce your original shapefile before loading anything (QGIS can do the same if you prefer GUI)

```
ogr2ogr yoursubsetshp.shp youroriginalshp.shp -sql 'SELECT * FROM youroriginalshp WHERE YOUR_COLUMN=VALUE'
```

You can find some SQL query for OGR/GDAL at the official doc http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql.html and http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_sql_sqlite.html